# v-model in icheck-box component not working in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a checkbox component but I am unable to do it. How can I create three checkboxs (using ichecks and inputs) and get all the selected ones using v-model in an array? The problem is that I can get the value of the clicked checkbox separately but I can not get all the values in array as it is suppose happen with vue's v-model. It seems that, they are getting lost somewhere. here my code

```
<html>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet">





   <div id='app'>
      <icheck  :value="'Jack'" id="jack" v-model="checkedNames"  > </icheck>
      <icheck  :value="'John'" id="john" v-model="checkedNames"  > </icheck>

      <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
      <label for="mike">Mike</label>
      <br> 
      <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
    </div>

 </html>


<script>
Vue.component('icheck', {
props: { 
    value:{ required: false }
},
template:  `
  <input type="checkbox"  >
`,
mounted: function () {
    var vm = this
    $(this.$el).iCheck({
      //checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-red',
      //radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square',
      increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    })
    .val(this.value)
    .trigger('ifChanged')
    // emit event on change.  here the problem
     .on('ifChanged', (event)=>{

        let isChecked = event.target.checked
        let val = event.target.value

       //  here the problem need an array
        vm.$emit('input',isChecked ? [val]:[])
    });


  },
  watch: {
    value: function (value) {
      // update value
      $(this.$el).val(value)
    }
  }

})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})


</script>
```

Comment: ichecks are actually not checkboxes, they are divs under the hood. you cannot use v-model here. Try listening to the state of ichecks and maintain your own array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

```
<icheck :val="'Jack'" id="jack" v-model="checkedNames"  > </icheck>
<icheck :val="'John'" id="john" v-model="checkedNames"  > </icheck>
```

```
props: { 
    val:{ required: true },
    value: { required: false }
},
....
```

```
// Check if the value is preset from the props and toggle check
if (this.value.includes(this.val)) {
  $(this.$el).iCheck('check');
}

$(this.$el).iCheck({
    //checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-red',
    //radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
})
.val(this.val)
.trigger('ifChanged')
.on('ifChanged', (event)=>{

    // create a local copy so as not to modify the prop
    let value = [].concat(this.value)

    // check if the array includes the value already
    if(value.includes(this.val)){
        // if it does remove it
        value.splice(value.indexOf(this.val), 1)
    } else {
        // if it doesn't add it
        value.push(this.val)
    }
    // emit the entire array
    vm.$emit('input', value)
});
```

Comment: that works but if I filled the array by code it would not work  . this.checkedNames = [ "John", "Jack", "Mike" ];

Comment: @Eliuber just call `.iCheck('check')` at the beginning of mounted.  Check the edit.

Comment: it works if the array start with values , when i change the value after inizializate not work for example if i set in the parent component in mounted. mounted: function () {
    this.checkedNames= ["John", "Jack", "Mike" ];
  },

Comment: i was tring with watch to value but i dont know how exactly

Answer (score 0):

I see what you try to do, but this only works with native checkboxes. if the `v-model` is an array and the element is a `checkbox`, it will change the `v-model` to something like `v-model="data[index]"`. This does not work with custom elements, as you try to do.